# how make a bulky send from an existing template

Tags: python, docusignapi

I have a form already done, So I want to make a bulk send with it, I already created the bulk sendind list, but in the example code from here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/bulk-sending-envelopes it looks like it is creating a new document how can I add my existing document to this bulk send?.

Comment: If the answer helped you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to modify the make_envelope() method used in Step 4 of that [Bulk Send code example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/bulk-sending-envelopes) with something like this:

```
def make_envelope(cls, args):
        """
        Creates envelope
        args -- parameters for the envelope:
        signer_email, signer_name, signer_client_id
        returns an envelope definition
        """

        # create the envelope definition
        envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
            status="sent",  # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
            template_id=args["template_id"]
        )
        # Create template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
        # to the template
        signer = TemplateRole(
            email=args["signer_email"],
            name=args["signer_name"],
            role_name="signer"
        )
        # Create a cc template role.
        cc = TemplateRole(
            email=args["cc_email"],
            name=args["cc_name"],
            role_name="cc"
        )

        # Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
        envelope_definition.template_roles = [signer, cc]
        return envelope_definition
```

Notice my template has two recipients (cc and signer). The template you reference will likely be different. [Here is the full source](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/bulk-sending-envelopes) to create an envelope using a template

Comment: Thank you for answering, just a couple a of questions, that use of TemplateRole will work  if I have a list of emails and name, I mean a structure like this:

`"signers": [{
        "signer_name": "Orlando Cuadra",
        "signer_email": "emailsigner1@hotmail.com",
        "cc_email": "emailcc1@gmail.com",
        "cc_name": "Responsable prueba"
    },
        {
            "signer_name": "Landy Cuadra",
            "signer_email": "emailsigner2@gmail.com",
            "cc_email": "emailcc2@gmail.com",
            "cc_name": "Responsable prueba2"
        }
    ]`

Comment: Correct. Just loop through your signers array and instantiate a new TemplateRole for each. Then populate your envelope_definition accordingly. Make sure that you are creating TemplateRoles to match your template. Ex. If your template expects 5 distinct "signer" recipients, you should instantiate 5 TemplateRole elements.

Comment: where can I see how much signer is my template is expecting?, by the way the template id is the one I get from list_templates()?

Comment: First question, To determine the recipients expected from a template, you can call the Templates:listRecipients method, which will return to you an object containing the expected recipients and tabs. Second question, correct.

Comment: If this was helpful, be sure to upvote and accept. For follow-up questions, go ahead and post a new question on SO.